# How to replace all occurrences of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data as follows

| Names |
| --- |
| 0002_○●○; B0024_○●; |
| 0032_●○; 0041_○●○; D0030_○●; |
| 022_○●●; A0071_○●; 0080_●●○; C0150_○○○; |

○● is a non-English name

I hope to get the following result

```
○●○; ○●; 
●○; ○●○; ○●; 
○●●; ○●; ●●○; ○○○;
```

I try to use replace to replace English, numbers, symbols

```
select REPLACE(Names, '%[^A-Za-z0-9]%', '')
from test
```

But it didn't work

How can I modify it?

Thank you

Comment: What is your actual SQL _database_?  For example, are you using MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, something else?

Comment: Does `select REPLACE(Names, '[A-Za-z0-9_]', '')` or `select REPLACE(Names, [A-Za-z0-9_], '')`  work ?

Comment: I use SQL Server

Comment: If use select REPLACE(Names, [A-Za-z0-9_],''), it will display Invalid column name

Comment: I thought SQL Server didn't support regex - unless it was added recently ?

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2017+, a combination of `TRANSLATE()` and `REPLACE()` is an option ( ... probably not the best one):

```
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(max) = N'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
SELECT 
   REPLACE(
      TRANSLATE(Names, @pattern, REPLICATE(N'A', LEN(@pattern))), 
      N'A', 
      N''
   ) AS Names
FROM (VALUES
   (N'0002_○●○; B0024_○●;'),
   (N'0032_●○; 0041_○●○; D0030_○●;'),
   (N'0022_○●●; A0071_○●; 0080_●●○; C0150_○○○;')
) test (Names)
```